# Does ZFS in 16.04 support raidz3?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, zfs

Does the "zfs" package in 16.04, installed via

```
sudo apt install zfs
```

support raidz3? I don't see it referenced at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS/ZPool. Is "zfs" just a pointer to "zfsutils-linux"? That would also answer my question as I know that package does support raidz3.

I'm hoping to upgrade a server running 14.04 with a raidz3 volume created via [ubuntu-zfs](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is "zfs" just a pointer to "zfsutils-linux"?

Yes, `zfs` is just a virtual package. If you try `sudo apt-get install zfs` it will automatically select `zfsutils-linux` for installation as shown below:

```
ron@ron:~$ sudo apt install zfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zfsutils-linux' instead of 'zfs'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc
  zfs-zed
Suggested packages:
  default-mta | mail-transport-agent nfs-kernel-server zfs-initramfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc
  zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
```